# Do I really need to create and return the collection for this method?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have seen people use `yield return`, although every time I try and use it in `foreach` it tells me something along the lines of: The body of CollectDictionary cannot be an iterator block because Dictionary<string, object> is not an interator interface type

I have a lot of methods line the following, is there a way to reduce boilerplate?

```
public Dictionary<string, object> CollectDictionary()
{
    var configLines = File.ReadAllLines(_file).Where(IsValidConfigLine);
    var configElements = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (var configElement in configLines)
    {
        configElements.Add(configElement.Split("=")[0], configElement.Split("=")[1]);
    }

    return configElements;
}
```

Comment: Woops, I just finished coding it, yes it is meant to grab [1] for the second argument.

Comment: afaik `yield return` only works for `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerator<T>`.

Comment: You can use `.ToDictionary` on the `IEnumerable` returned from the `File.ReadAllLines().Where()` chain to convert it into dictionary, using separate per-value projections for entry key and entry value. See [Enumerable.ToDictionary docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__)

Comment: well thats because a dictonary isnt an iterator interface type (IEnumerable ect).

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the amount of code by using [`.ToDictionary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netcore-3.1).

```
public Dictionary<string, object> CollectDictionary()
{
    string[] configLines =  new string[]
        {
            "foo1=bar1",
            "foo2=bar2",
            "foo3=bar3",
            "foo4=bar4",
        };
        
        return configLines.Select(configElement => configElement.Split("="))
                          .ToDictionary(splt => splt[0], splt => (object)splt[1]);
}
```

This should return the following Dciotnary

```
{
    { "foo1", "bar1" },
    { "foo2", "bar2" },
    { "foo3", "bar3" },
    { "foo4", "bar4" }
}
```